# PyPDF2 returns only empty lines for some files

Tags: python-3.x, adobe, ocr, pypdf

I am working on a script that "reads" PDF files and and then automatically renames the files it recognizes from a dictionary. PyPDF2 however only returns empty lines for some PDFs, while working fine for others. The code for reading the files:

```
import PyPDF2

# File name
file = 'sample.pdf'

# Open File
with open(file, "rb") as f:
    # Read in file
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f)

    # Check number of pages
    number_of_pages = pdfReader.numPages
    print(number_of_pages)

    # Get first page
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)

    # Extract text from page 1
    text = pageObj.extractText()        

print(text)
```

It does get the number of pages correctly, so it is able to open the PDF.

If I replace the print(text) by repr(text) for files it doesn't read, I get something like:

```
"'\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\nn\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n'"
```

Weirdly enough, when I enhance (OCR) the files with Adobe, the script performs slightly worse. It Recognized 140 out of 800 files and after enhancing just 110.

The PDFs are machine readable/searchable, because I am able to copy/paste text to Notepad. I tested some files with "pdfminer" and it does show some text, but also throws in a lot of errors. If possible I like to keep working with PyPDF2.

Specifications of the software I am using:
Windows: 10.0.15063
Python: 3.6.1
PyPDF: 1.26.0
Adobe version: 17.009.20058

Anyone any suggestions? Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Nope. This problem only occurred on a few percentage of my documents. I haven't re-tested since then...

Comment: @Hoenie how did you resolve your problem? I meen which the library did you use instead pyPdf2

Comment: pdfminer, but that one was also not reading some PDFs correctly. combining both got my quite far though...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, i fixed it using another python library called [slate](https://github.com/timClicks/slate)
Fortunately, i found a [fork](https://github.com/TakesxiSximada/slate3k) that works in Python 3.6.5

```
import slate3k as slate

with open(file.pdf,'rb') as f:
    extracted_text = slate.PDF(f)
print(extracted_text)
```